# Continuous function $l_2 \to \Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Define $g:(l_2,d_1) \to (\Bbb R,d_2)$ by $\displaystyle g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}$. Test whether $g$ is continuous or NOT.

**Attempt :**
Take $\displaystyle x=\left (\frac{1}{n},\cdots ,\frac{1}{n} ,\cdots \right)\in l_2$ and $y=(0,0, \cdots , 0,\cdots)\in l_2$.

Now , $$d_2(g(x),g(y))=|g(x)-g(y)|=\left|\sum\frac{1}{n^2}-0\right|=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$
and $$d_1(x,y)=\left(\sum \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}.$$

So , $d_2(g(x),g(y))>d_1(x,y)$. So $g$ is **NOT** continuous.

Check whether it is correct or wrong.

Comment: How is that checking continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe $x = (x_n), y=(y_n) \in \ell^2$, then we see
\begin{align}
d_2(g(x), g(y))=|g(x)-g(y)| = \left|\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x_n-y_n}{n}\right| \leq \sqrt{\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}}\sqrt{\sum^\infty_{n=1}|x_n-y_n|^2}= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}d_1(x, y)
\end{align}
which is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Where my fault in my answer ?

Comment: @S717717 You weren't checking continuity. What you claimed is similar to saying $y=2x$ is not continuous.